# geom_sf arguments only working for one facet with ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, ggmap, r-sf

I'm working on a faceted map, with two panels. For some reason, the right panel does not show up as expected. The first one is displayed as expected, but for some reason the second one does not. I'm working with a different data set, but I've created a reproducible example here:

```
library(ggmap)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)

BackgroundMap<- ggmap(get_map(c(left = -4.76, bottom = 41.38, right = 9.55, top = 51.09), maptype="roadmap", source = "google"))    

worldmap <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = 'medium', type = 'map_units', returnclass = 'sf')

france <- worldmap[worldmap$name == 'France',]
swiss <- worldmap[worldmap$name == 'Switzerland',]
TwoCountries <- rbind(france, swiss)

BackgroundMap + geom_sf(data=TwoCountries, inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = "red", alpha = 0.4) + facet_wrap(~admin) ## Switzerland map does not show up in red
```

[image]

The faceted maps show up as expected when the ggmap-argument is replaced with a normal ggplot:

```
ggplot() + geom_sf(data=TwoCountries, inherit.aes = FALSE, fill = "red", alpha = 0.4) + facet_wrap(~admin) ## both panels show up as expected
```

[image]

*What I want is basically a hybrid between the first and second image: I would like to have both countries show up in red (as in the second image), but with a ggmap as a background (as in the first image).* Has anyone encountered a similar problem, or can push me into the right direction to get both panels look similar?

EDIT: After some suggestions, it now seems that may/may not show the desired output depending on the window size of the zoom plot. For example, the plot panel does not show Switzerland in red, while a separate, small window plot does. In a fully zoomed window plot, Switzerland does not show up in red. See images below:
[image: Two different plot results, depending on the window size of the zoomed plot]
[image: Full screen zoom plot]

Comment: How would you like the second panel to look? Running your example, the map of Switzerland shows up in red for me.

Comment: I've added a description how I wanted the panel to look like. Also added images of my output.

Comment: This is how your first map shows up for me: https://imgur.com/tGpFw5x

Comment: This is my session info, in case you want to compare R and/or package versions: https://imgur.com/rC3BBTx

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my R version, and also ggplot2. Those were still on the previous version. The map is now sort of working as it shows up as expected in the plots tab. But when I click 'zoom', the enlarged version is again not showing up correctly. I'm a bit puzzled, why this is and how to solve that.

Comment: Would you be able to share an image of what it looks like for you? The plot looks the same for me when I click "Zoom" - https://imgur.com/Da3P5Yb.

Comment: Thanks, I've added two images how the different zoom-levels seem to affect the plot output.